# В каком виде лучше хранить информацию о юзере

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, если вкратце, то я делаю небольшой стартап, там есть страница, где клиент может написать сообщение (он не авторизованный). После того как он добавит сообщение, оно добавится в БД, вот и думаю - как лучше хранить данные о клиенте? IP - не варик, это понятно, может хранить PHPSESSID? просто нужно как-то проверять, добавлял ли он что либо в течении какого-то промежутка времени

Comment: Если используете аналитику от гугла, можно завязаться на __utma метку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% вы всё равно не узнаете, так как может быть использован другой браузер\прокси\виртуальная машина\виртуальный сервер и тд.

Я бы хранил информацию в двух частях:

1) ip, юзерагент, сессию, поставил бы куку

2) так называемый 'hardware id', сведение которые удалось собрать яваскриптом, тут может быть: разрешение экрана, глубина цвета, версия процессора, язык ос и тд.

далее уже в базе смотрите что совпадает, а что нет.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант можно организовать социальную авторизацию